# The InnerException message was 'Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an object graph is '65536'.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I can see that this question has been asked several times, however they are all concerning WCF. After searching for a while, I have been unable to find a solution to this error.

I have a WinForms application that pulls data from a web service. The web service is written in WebForms / asp.net.

My code to connect to the web service is:

```
Dim _DownloadStock As srShopDownload.shop_downloadsSoapClient
Dim binding As New STKBinding("STKBinder")
NewEndPoint = New EndpointAddress("https://www.example.com/web_services/downloads.asmx")
            _DownloadStock = New srShopDownload.shop_downloadsSoapClient(binding._Binder, NewEndPoint)
_StockcodesList = _DownloadStock.GetStockcodes
```

My code for the _Binder is

```
Public Sub New(ByVal BinderName As String)

    _Binder = New BasicHttpBinding()
    _Binder.Name = BinderName

    _Binder.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    _Binder.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    _Binder.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
    _Binder.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    _Binder.AllowCookies = False
    _Binder.BypassProxyOnLocal = False
    _Binder.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard

    _Binder.MaxBufferSize = 100000000
    _Binder.MaxBufferPoolSize = 12000000
    _Binder.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 100000000

    _Binder.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text
    _Binder.TextEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
    _Binder.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed
    _Binder.UseDefaultWebProxy = True

    _Binder.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 2147483647
    _Binder.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 2147483647
    _Binder.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 2147483647
    _Binder.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 2147483647
    _Binder.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 2147483647

    _Binder.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
    _Binder.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None
    _Binder.Security.Transport.Realm = ""

    _Binder.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName
    _Binder.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Default
    _Binder.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport

End Sub
```

On the web service side, it's just a basic function:

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function GetStockcodes() As List(Of Stockcodes)

    Return GetStockcodes()

End Function
```

I've seen answers that you should change the serviceBehaviors on the client and server but I don't know how to do it without using WCF.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce this, but I did not hit the limit in WebServices. Not even for list of 1000000 objects, nor list of 1000 objects with 1000 subobjects in each. Are you sure that GetStockcodes does not depend on another WCF service and your exception is not rethrown from there? Can you inspect your message to see if the exception comes from server side or client side?

Comment: I actually found the solution. It's machine specific. So, you need to adjust the settings in the .NET machine.config. I tried to post the answer but the XML wasn't showing, even though a made it "code." I just don't want to get downvoted on the answer because of the code formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround, just putting here in case anyone comes up with the same issue.

1. Open this folder on the PC. It is the .NET Framework folder: %windir%\Microsoft.NET\
2. Within this directory you should see folders: Framework and Framework64 (in 64-bit environments). Both of those contain a few folders with names of particular .NET versions (e.g. v2.0.50727). You need to browse through every folder and see if it contains CONFIG directory and inside a file named machine.config. (Or just search for machine.config)
3. Open for edit every machine.config file and under the system.serviceModel node add the following subnode:

```
<commonBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </endpointBehaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </serviceBehaviors>
</commonBehaviors>
```

4. After editing it should look something like this:

```
<system.serviceMode>
    (...)
    <extensions>
        (...)
    </extensions>
    <client>
        (...)
    </client>
    <commonBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          </endpointBehaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          </serviceBehaviors>
    </commonBehaviors> 
    (...)
</system.serviceModel>
```

5. If the system.serviceModel node is missing in the configuration file, you need to create this node manually.
6. Restart the application. You might need to reboot the PC if it still doesn't work.

I found the solution at this [link](https://www.codetwo.com/kb/error-of-deserializing-object-graph/). Just put the answer here in case the page goes down in the future.